# VBScript how to join WScript.Arguments?

Tags: windows-7, vbscript, command-line-arguments

I am trying to join the arguments to a string to be passed to another script. The following:

```
WScript.Echo(Join(WScript.Arguments))
```

gives me an error:

```
Error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment
Code: 800A01C2
```

What is wrong with that syntax?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`WshArgument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ss1ysb2a%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) objects are not arrays, so you can't use `Join()` on them. What you can do is something like this:

```
ReDim arr(WScript.Arguments.Count-1)
For i = 0 To WScript.Arguments.Count-1
  arr(i) = WScript.Arguments(i)
Next

WScript.Echo Join(arr)
```

Comment: This answer doesn't work when some of the arguments had been given with quotes, e.g. `"C:\Program Files\"`.

Comment: @RolandIllig The answer works perfectly fine for the problem described in the question. Of course it may not work for [your particular problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53465665/1630171), but then again, I wasn't answering your question in the first place.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers If your Answer does not work if some of the arguments have been given with quotes, then it does not "work[] perfectly fine for the problem described in the question." Nothing in the Question says that none of the arguments to be concatenated will be surrounded by quotation marks, or that it is okay to omit them in them in the concatenation if they are included. Your Answer thus fails in some use cases that fit the criteria described in the Question.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution can be done with ArrayList object from the system:

```
Set oAL = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
For Each oItem In Wscript.Arguments: oAL.Add oItem: Next
WScript.Echo Join(oAL.ToArray, " ")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
            ReDim arr(WScript.Arguments.Count-1)
            For i = 0 To WScript.Arguments.Count-1
              arr(i) = """"+WScript.Arguments(i)+""""
            Next
            WScript.Echo Join(arr)
```

this will add quotes for each argument, 
you can then remove it in the batch file with %~1 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function that I use. It will return all the arguments whether they contain quotes or not in a string that you can pass to another script.

```
Function GetArguments()

 Dim Args, Arg

 If WSH.Arguments.Count > 0 Then
  For Each Arg In WSH.Arguments
   Args = Args & """" & Arg & """ "
  Next
  Args = " """"" & Trim(Args) & """"""
 End If

 GetArguments = Args

End Function
```