Finding the target of a shortcut file that supports unicode characters and long paths in Powershell
There's a really nice post that outlines how to get the shortcut target of a .lnk shortcut file that unfortunately doesn't work for neither Unicode characters nor long paths. Testing the accepted answer in my environment reveals some interesting results.
Original code from that answer:
$Shell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$Target = $Shell.CreateShortcut('<full-path-to-shortcut>').TargetPath


If the path to the shortcut file is long, the $Shell.CreateShortcut cannot read the file
If the target has Unicode characters (Japanese, Chinese, Korean etc.) then the target becomes ??? and cannot be used.
If the path to the shortcut has Unicode characters in it then the shortcut cannot be created with $Shell.CreateShortcut

The least upvoted answer provides an alternative of using the Win32_ShortcutFile class:
$Path = '<full-path-to-shortcut>' -replace "\\", "\\"
$ShortcutFile = Get-WmiObject Win32_ShortcutFile -Filter "name = '$Path'"
$Target = $ShortcutFile.Target

This will work with Unicode characters but will fail for both network/UNC paths (like \\Server\Share\Shortcut.lnk) and will also fail using the UNC qualifier (\\?\UNC\Server\Share\Shortcut.lnk)
Is there any other way to get the target of a shortcut file that supports long paths in both the shortcut path and the target, as well as Unicode characters in both the shortcut path and the target?
EDIT: This question is not "how can I set the console to Unicode?" but rather "how can I read the shortcut target of a .lnk shortcut file when either the shortcut path or the shortcut link target is both longer than 260 characters and may or may not contain unicode characters?". $Shell.CreateShortcut() doesn't return long paths even when long paths are enabled. Example:
$ShortcutFile = "C:\users\administrator\desktop\myshortcut.lnk"
#This is just for illustration to show you what the link target of myshortcut.lnk is, I don't use this variable in code
$ShortcutLinkTarget = "\\Server\Share\Additional folder here\More text\More levels\Planning\Some more tests\123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 0\123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 0\123456\This file name should definitely show up but it doesn't.txt"

$Shell.CreateShortcut($ShortcutFile)

FullName         : C:\users\administrator\desktop\myshortcut.lnk
Arguments        :
Description      :
Hotkey           :
IconLocation     : ,0
RelativePath     :
TargetPath       : \\Server\Share\Additional folder here\More text\More 
                   levels\Planning\Some more tests\123456789 123456789 
                   123456789 123456789 123456789 0\ 123456789 123456789 
                   123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 
                   123456789 123456789 123456789 0\123456\This file nam
WindowStyle      : 1
WorkingDirectory : \\Server\Share\Additional folder here\More text\More 
                   levels\Planning\Some more tests\123456789 123456789 
                   123456789 123456789 123456789 0\ 123456789 123456789 
                   123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 
                   123456789 123456789 123456789 0\123456

This question has two issues: unicode characters were not properly displaying, but more importantly: long paths in shortcut targets are still not displaying. Unicode bit seems solved, but I still need to make it work for long paths. Using the 8.3 shortpath works for the shortcut file itself, but the link target returned from $Shell.CreateShortcut() cannot return anything longer than 246 characters. This is what I'm looking to solve.

I guess you will need to correctly set the encoding of you script file and/or your console: $OutputEncoding = [Console]::InputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding =  New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49481797/1701026. Besides, as a workaround you might consider to use the 8.3 name in the shortcut: (New-Object -ComObject Scripting.FileSystemObject).GetFile('<full-path-to-shortcut>').ShortName.

Thank you! It doesn't seem to have changed the behaviour of the shell command as the FullName output of the shortcut generated still has ??? even after setting the OutputEncoding. The Get-WmiObject approach seems unaffected (which makes sense since that only has issues with long paths). I will try the 8.3 workaround to see how that works!

4 months later but yes! This worked! I couldn't use .ShortName as that only used the file name, but I could use the network path as is with the (New-Object -ComObject Scripting.FileSystemObject).GetFile and that correctly gave me the full path for longer characters, and then I could use .ShortPath with [IO.FileInfo]::New() to validate the .Exists property. Thank you so much! If you add this as an answer I can accept it as the correct solution :)

Thanks for the feedback, I decided, to close the case as a dupplicate. The referred issues are very similar but most of all the helpful answers from @mklement0 are already very extensive and I don't think there much to add for this case. As an aside: Get-WmiObject have been deprecated in PowerShell Core. Please use CIM cmdlets..

Noted, I'll see if that helps. It looks like even with the 8.3 shortname the $Shell.CreateShortcut() can't return the full target path and gets cut off at 246 characters regardless. I'll verify the linked answers in the coming days!

Found the solution! But it was found here by @zett42: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74734553/1618897  I was using the wrong $Shell, by using their suggestion it worked for long paths too. Sorry for asking generic questions but I don't know what to do in this case: do I just add that link to the question body so that people get redirected to that answer when they see this post or what do I do?

Good find, @TanakaSaito. I've added a link to that post as the first duplicate, which should be enough.
